# How to crop an image in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to place the bottom circle on the left side. But, the circle changes position when I view it on the mobile phone screen. How can I correct that?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <img class="circletop-img" src="images/bg-pattern-top.svg" alt="cicletop-img">
   <img class="circlebottom-img" src="images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg" alt="circlebottom-img">
   <img class="card-img" src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="card-img">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circlebottom-img {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;    
    right: -7%;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

That gives me this:

[image]

But, what I want is this:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide a working example or at least how this element is constructed in HTML & CSS with its parent?

Answer (score 1):

You can just place the two circles based on the viewport width, using the `vw` unit, so you can say that the first circle will be placed on `70vw` from the right, and the second one will be placed on `70vw` from left, or play with it as you like.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <img class="circletop-img" src="images/bg-pattern-top.svg" alt="cicletop-img">
   <img class="circlebottom-img" src="images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg" alt="circlebottom-img">
   <img class="card-img" src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="card-img">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.circlebottom-img {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;    
    left: 70vw;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might take a try like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img class="circletop-img" src="images/bg-pattern-top.svg" alt="cicletop-img">
   <img class="circlebottom-img" src="images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg" alt="circlebottom-img">
   <img class="card-img" src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="card-img">
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.circlebottom-img {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;    
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```